# Подсчет элементов с нужными атрибутами

Tags: jquery

Здравствуйте.

Как подсчитать элементы, которые не спрятаны (прячу функцией `hide()`)?

```
<div id="result">
<div class="list" id="8">balabadfd</div>
<div class="list" id="1">bdfsfsfs</div> // допустим, спрятал с hide()
<div class="list" id="6">balabadfd</div>
<div class="list" id="4">balabadfd</div> // допустим, спрятал с hide()
<div class="list" id="8">balabadfd</div>
</div>
```

`$('div.list').length;` это подсчитывает все и те, что спрятал.

Answer (score 2):

еще короче

```
$("div.list:visible").length
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так

```
var total = 0;
var list = $('div.list');
list.each(function( el ){
  if( el.css('display') === 'none' ) { ++total; }
})
console.log( total );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.list[style*='display:none']").length
```